# Jquery validation on "tags Input" plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am making use of the popular [Bassistance jquery validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation) to validate my forms. On the same form I am making use of [xoxco's jQuery Tags Input Plugin](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/).

I am able to validate all the form fields on my form, except the one that is being used by the "tags input" plugin.

The reason is, the original input is being hidden and new ones drawn by the plugin.

> **[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kKyAQ/8/)**

Any help to apply my validation style to the tags input would be appreciated, Thanx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do a trick by validating a dummy text field with a custom method which will validate your tag field.

#### HTML:

```
<form id="someForm" name="someForm" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1"/>
    <input id="tagsx" name="tagsx" type="text" />
    <input id="dummy" name="dummy" type="text" /><!-- dummy text field -->
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

#### CSS:

```
/*To hide dummy text field*/
#dummy{
    visibility: hidden!Important;
    height:1px;
    width:1px;
}
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.validator.addMethod("checkTags", function(value) { //add custom method
        //Tags input plugin converts input into div having id #YOURINPUTID_tagsinput
        //now you can count no of tags
        return ($("#tagsx_tagsinput").find(".tag").length > 0);
    });

    $("#someForm").validate( {
        rules: {
            txt1:"required",
            dummy:"checkTags"
        },
        messages: {
            txt1: "Required",
            dummy: "Required"
        }
    });

    $('#tagsx').tagsInput({
        width: 'auto',
        autocomplete_url: 'http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/test/fake_json_endpoint.html' 
    });
});
```

Comment: I like this approach, however, to make things fair for the bounty, can you get a jsfiddle example up and running? thanx

Answer (score 9):

Two problems:

1. All of your fields must have a `name`. Validate will not behave properly if the attribute is not there.
2. You must validate hidden fields in your case. What you'll want to do is use `ignore: []` to include validation of hidden fields.

All in all your code should look like this:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="someForm" name="someForm" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="required-field" class="required"/>
    <input id="tagsx" type="text" name="tags" class="required" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#someForm").validate({
        ignore: []
    });
    $('#tagsx').tagsInput({
        width: 'auto',
        autocomplete_url: 'http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/test/fake_json_endpoint.html'
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/5eC5B/

Note that you will have to use `errorPlacement` or similar to get the error message to show up properly.

Comment: This is a great answer. Sort of a "missing manual" for jquery.validate

Answer (score 5):

The default setting of the validate-Plugin is `ignore: ":hidden"` which uses `jQuery.not()` to exclude everything from the ignore-option.

If you want to include hidden fields you can use this:

```
$("#myform").validate({
   ignore: ""
});
```

---

In your case use this Javascript-code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#someForm").validate({
       ignore: ""
    });
    $('#tagsx').tagsInput({
        width: 'auto',
        autocomplete_url: 'http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/test/fake_json_endpoint.html'
    });
});
```

---

**Update:** As I saw in the validation-code the `name`-Attribute is strongly required, because the plugin stores everything with the `name`. Even if you add just `ignore: ""` to your code, it will give one validation-error, because it's stored with the same `name` and the name is `null`.

Here's a working JSFiddle:

> [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kKyAQ/15/)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery validate by default ignores fields that aren't visible. To override this behavior use `$("#someForm").validate({ignore:""});`